# Continuous sum of $n$ functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_i:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$. If we know that $f=f_1+...+f_n$ is continuous, does it follow that each $f_i$ is continuous as well?

For $n=1,2$ this is true but is it true for $n>2$?

Answer (score 2):

For $n=2$ this is false. Consider any discontinuous function $g$ and set $f_1 = g$, $f_2 = -g$.

EDIT: But it is true as long as all but one of the $f_i$ are known to be continuous. Assume e.g. that only $f_1$ is **not known** to be continuous. Then $f_1 = f - f_2 - \dots - f_n$ is continuous as well.